# join after group by condition in a nested select query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Hi I'm new to sql and I'm trying to solve this query:
find the registration numbers(MATRICOLA) and the surnames(COGNOME) of the employees that have the salary greater than at least 10% than the average salary of their department.

```
IMPIEGATO(employees)
DIPARTIMENTO(department)
```

[image: Here are the TABLES]

```
SELECT *
from (
  SELECT *
  FROM IMPIEGATO imp1, 
       DIPARTIMENTO dip1
  where imp1.dipartimento_codice_fk = dip1.codice
), (
  SELECT dip.codice, 1.1*avg(imp.stipendio) AS "STIPENDIO_MEDIO_10"
  FROM IMPIEGATO imp
    JOIN DIPARTIMENTO dip ON dip.CODICE=imp.DIPARTIMENTO_CODICE_FK
  GROUP BY dip.codice
)
```

I can't add this where condition to get just the results I need `WHERE dip.codice=dip1.codice`.
This is the error I get

> ORA-00904: "DIP1"."CODICE": identificativo non valido
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Errore alla riga: 255, colonna: 18

Comment: the error occurs only when i add the where condition, i called "CODICE" with the same dot notation in the join btw im postiong the ddl too

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the `CODICE` outside these two subqueries with an alias(`dip` or `dip1`) given to the `DIPARTIMENTO` in the subquery. (Scope of the alias is within the subquery only)

Anyway, a better solution is to use the `analytical function` as following:

```
SELECT MATRICOLA, COGNOME
FROM
    ( SELECT
            EMP.MATRICOLA, EMP.COGNOME, EMP.STIPENDIO,
            AVG(EMP.STIPENDIO) OVER(
                PARTITION BY EMP.DIPARTIMENTO_CODICE_FK
            ) AS AVG_SALARY_DEPT
        FROM IMPIEGATO EMP
             JOIN DIPARTIMENTO DEPT ON EMP.DIPARTIMENTO_CODICE_FK = DEPT.CODICE
    )
WHERE STIPENDIO >= 1.1 * AVG_SALARY_DEPT;
```

You can also use your own query with little bit of changes in it. Changes are mentioned in the comments in the following query:

```
SELECT t1.MATRICOLA, t1.COGNOME 
from (
  SELECT *
  FROM IMPIEGATO imp1, 
       DIPARTIMENTO dip1
  where imp1.dipartimento_codice_fk = dip1.codice
) t1 join -- given alias
(
  SELECT dip.codice, 1.1*avg(imp.stipendio) AS "STIPENDIO_MEDIO_10"
  FROM IMPIEGATO imp
    JOIN DIPARTIMENTO dip ON dip.CODICE=imp.DIPARTIMENTO_CODICE_FK
  GROUP BY dip.codice
) t2 on t1.codice = t2.codice -- given alias 
                              -- and added the join condition with proper alias(t1, t2)
where t1.stipendio >= t2.STIPENDIO_MEDIO_10 -- added the condition to fetch desired result
```

Cheers!!